# DES and ICryptoTransform

Tags: transform, des, cryptoapi, crypt

This method works fine in a program I've made. However I cannot really understand what is happening and where the encryption is actually performed. I read the related description from MSDN but not much information is given.
Can someone explain what is happening in general especially in line 8 and 9 please.

```
 public byte[] Decrypt(byte[] input, byte[] key, byte[] iv)
    {
        DES des = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
        des.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
        des.Padding = PaddingMode.None;
        des.Key = key;

        ICryptoTransform ct = des.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
        byte[] result = ct.TransformFinalBlock(input, 0, input.Length);

        return result;
    }
```

Comment: ECB mode does not require any IV. this link might help to understand how the different mode works. http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-38a/sp800-38a.pdf

Answer (score 1):

If you want to understand what is going on, you should read about block cipher operations here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29

In a nutshell, block ciphers chaining causes the input of one block operation to be fed into the next block operation. This obscures any block-level patterns in the ciphertext. Since there is a chaining structure, the last block gets an input from the second last block, and so on... until the second block gets an input from the first block. Now the first block needs to get an input from something, but there are no preceding blocks. So we use something called an Initialization Vector (iv) to start it off. This IV does not need to be secret like the key, but it does need to have a low probability of re-use (otherwise the attacker can use it to correlate the first blocks of all your ciphertexts). Typically random numbers are used, or sometimes increasing sequence numbers.

In regard to the specific call:

Your method works to decrypt a single block using DES. (Which is nowadays considered out of date and insecure, by the way, please consider using AES instead - the block cipher structures remain the same so all you need to do is swap the library). Anyway,

Since you're using a cipher in ECB mode, each block is decrypted independently with the same initialization vector, which is provided to your Decrypt method call. The call to CreateDecryptor initializes a decryption object using the provided secret key and initialization vector.

The actual decryption is performed using the call to TransformFinalBlock. The arguments are the input byte array, and then an offset and a length parameter (used for when you don't want to decrypt the entire byte array). In this case you do want to use the entire byte array so the starting offset is 0 and the size is the length of the whole byte array.

One thing you should probably add is to check that the input byte array is the correct block size for your cipher, otherwise it will throw an exception. In the case of DES, this is 64 bits. If you switch to AES as I recommended it will be 128 bits.